# SwiftUI Digital Crown stepping through numbers not working

Tags: swiftui, watchos-6

I'm bashing my face against a wall trying to figure out why I can't get the `.digitalCrownRotation` feature to work on a `Text` UI Component in SwiftUI for WatchOS.

Here's my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ButtonView: View {
    @State private var isFocused = false
    @State private var value: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            print("clicked")
        }) {
            Text("\(value)")
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .focusable { self.isFocused = $0 }
            .digitalCrownRotation(self.$value, from: 0, through: 9, by: 1, sensitivity: .medium, isContinuous: true, isHapticFeedbackEnabled: true)
        }
        .background(self.isFocused ? Color.green : Color.white)
    }
}
```

Everything worked fine up until the pointer where I tried to add the `.digitalCrownRotation` functionality.

Whenever I try to build I'm faced with the following 2 build fail messages:

> Argument type 'Int.Stride' (aka 'Int') does not conform to expected type 'BinaryFloatingPoint'
>   Argument type 'Int' does not conform to expected type 'BinaryFloatingPoint'

I'm basically trying to use the digital crown to step through numbers (integers) from 0 to 9 when the buttons are focused. But it's not working and I'm not sure what to do to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is declaration

> ````swift
>     public func digitalCrownRotation<V>(_ binding: Binding<V>, from minValue: V, through 
>                    maxValue: V, by stride: V.Stride? = nil, sensitivity: DigitalCrownRotationalSensitivity = .high, 
>                    isContinuous: Bool = false, isHapticFeedbackEnabled: Bool = true) -> some View 
>                    where V : BinaryFloatingPoint, V.Stride : BinaryFloatingPoint ```
> ````

so as seen and error reports `V` type (which is detected from your provided binding) should be floating point, but your `value` is `Int`, which is not floating point, so fix is simple

```
@State private var value: Double = 0
```

Comment: Thanks, this has resolved the bug. But now for the actual label value, I've converted it to an `Int` just so that I get the formatting I need, it's a little bit janky in the experience of changing values, I'd like it to be a more step transition. But it doesn't feel very intuitive on the digit crown. Any ideas on how to solve that?

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle I'm seeing the same issue trying to use the Digital Crown with an integer-based stepper. Did you manage to solve the jankyness?

Comment: I gave up on Swift all together and I decided to abandon my iOS watch app development ventures xD

Answer (score 1):

I came across this post as I was facing a similar situation. I solved the jankyness of the integer value by rounding up/down/tonearest based of the velocity of the crown.

```
@State crownValue: Double
@State integerValue: Int

Text("(integerValue)")
  .focusable(true)
  .digitalCrownRotation(
       detent: $values.crownValue,
       from: 0,
       through: 100,
       by: 1,
       sensitivity: .low,
       isContinuous: false,
       isHapticFeedbackEnabled: true,
       onChange: { crownEvent in
           integerValue = round(value: crownEvent.offset, velocity: crownEvent.velocity)
       })

private func round(value: Double, velocity: CDouble) -> Double {
   let roundingRule: FloatingPointRoundingRule
   switch velocity {
       case let x where x < 0: roundingRule = .up
       case let x where x == 0: roundingRule = .toNearestOrAwayFromZero
       case let x where x > 0: roundingRule = .down
       default: roundingRule = .toNearestOrAwayFromZero
   }
   return value.rounded(roundingRule)
}
```